# React Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentIndex' of null

Tags: reactjs

I have a gallery component that showcases images from the components prop.

The gallery component shows 1 image at a time, but has 2 loaded randomly form the array for animation purposes.

Everything sounds great, but I'm getting this error in console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentIndex' of null
```

Don't know why this would be null.

Here is the ViewGallery.js component:

```
import React from 'react';


class ViewGallery extends React.Component {

  getInitialState(){
    return {
      currentIndex: 0,
      count: 0
    };
  }

  generateImagesDOM(){
    return imagesDOM;
  }

 handleClick() {
   let currentIndex = this.state.currentIndex;

    if(currentIndex === this.state.count - 1){
      currentIndex = 0;
    } else {
      currentIndex ++;
    }

    this.setState({
      currentIndex: currentIndex
    });


    $(this.images[currentIndex]).removeClass('active');

  }

  render() {
    let images = this.props.images;
    let startWith = this.props.startWith;
    let count = this.props.count;
    let imagesDOM = [];
    let i = startWith || 0;

    if(typeof count === 'number' && count > 0){
      images = images.slice(0, count - 1);
    }

    let length = images.length;

    if(startWith > 0 && startWith < length){
      let images0 = images.slice(0, startWith);
      let images1 = images.slice(startWith);
      images = images1.concat(images0);
    }


    for ( ; i<length ; i+=1 ) {

      let className = "image";
      if(i === this.state.currentIndex){
        className += " active";
      }
      imagesDOM.push(<div className={className}><img src={images[i]} /></div>);
    }

    this.state.count = length;

    return <div className="gallery" onClick={this.handleClick}>{imagesDOM}</div>
  }
}

ViewGallery.propTypes = {
    images: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    startWith: React.PropTypes.number,
    count: React.PropTypes.number
}

export default ViewGallery;
```

Comment: `bind` your `handleClick` event to `this` -> `this.handleClick.bind(this)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `class` pattern for creating React components, you should set the initial state in the constructor, not in `getInitialState()`.

```
class ViewGallery extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      currentIndex: 0,
      count: 0
    };
  }

  /* rest of your code */
}
```

Also, your methods, unlike the previous `createClass` pattern, are no longer bound automatically the component instance, you have to bind them yourself. Either:

```
onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
```

or

```
onClick={e => this.handleClick(e)}
```

See [this blog post from 2015 January](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html) on the differences between `extends React.Component` and `React.createClass()` component creation patterns.